# Azure Storage and Service Bus - One Connection per Asp.Net Application or per Request?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I was wondering whether anyone knows specifically what the best practice is for using and potentially sharing or creating new connections from an Asp.Net Web Application to Azure Storage and -ServiceBus?

Basically the Asp.Net application receives file uploads, stores them in an Azure Storage Blog and sends a message to an Azure ServiceBus Queue to notify background processors.

While the background processors have persistent connections, I was wondering what the correct approach is for the frontend, Asp.Net application - should new connections be made on a per-request level to Azure Storage and likewise to the ServiceBus Queue or should I share an application-lifetime created connection for each of those two?

What's the recommended way here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the service bus side of things you should try and re-use client connections as there is an over-head associated with re-creating them. More details are in the following Microsoft article about performance on Azure Service Bus:

[Best Practices for Performance Improvements Using Service Bus Brokered Messaging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh528527.aspx)

This is less of an issue with the Azure storage client which does not manage open connections in the same way.

Comment: Thanks Ben for the clarification & link!